# Maintain sum of number in given HTML number fields

Tags: jquery, math

Lets discuss this in analogy of stock, say I receive stock of 20 units for a SKU, now I have three warehouses where I want to distribute this stock, each warehouse have number field in front of them.

```
Warehouse1  [ 20^] <-- this is html number field and 20 is assigned to first warehouse by default
Warehouse2  [   ^]
Warehouse2  [   ^]
```

Now if user changes value for warehouse2 to 10, then warehouse1 value should change to 10. subsequently if user put 5 in warehouse3 then it should get adjusted in either warehouse1 or warehouse2.

following is code I am trying with

```
    function recalculateStockAssignment(ele) {
        var prev_val = parseFloat(jQuery(ele).data('prev'));
        var dif = prev_val - parseFloat(jQuery(ele).val());
        jQuery("input[name='" + jQuery(ele).prop('name') + "']").not(ele).each(
                function () {
                    if (jQuery(this).val() > 0 && dif < 0)
                    {
                        var val = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val()) + parseFloat(dif);
                        console.log("difference is minus", val);
                        jQuery(this).val(parseFloat(val));
                    } else
                    {
                        var val = parseFloat(jQuery(this).val()) + parseFloat(dif);
                        console.log("difference is positive", val);
                        if( parseFloat(jQuery) )
                        jQuery(this).val(parseFloat(val));
                    console.log(this);

                    }
                });
                jQuery(ele).data('prev', jQuery(ele).val());
            }
```

This is not working as expected, and I am getting feeling that some expert mind can come up with simpler solution.

Your help is much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should cover your question or at least get you going on the right track - make sure you set your total_stock variable. This solution is designed for integer values:

```js
   var total_stock = 20
   $(document).ready(function(){
      
    
      $(".warehouse").on("change",function(){
         recalculateStockAssignment($(this))
      })
   })
   
   function recalculateStockAssignment(ele) {
       if(ele.val() > total_stock){
         ele.val(total_stock)
       }
       var changed_val = ele.val()
       var cur_id = ele.prop('id')
       var temp_total = 0
       $(".warehouse").each(function(){
          temp_total+=parseInt($(this).val())
       })
       var diff =   total_stock - temp_total
       
       
       $(".warehouse").each(function(){
          
          if($(this).prop('id')!=cur_id){
             var val=parseInt($(this).val())
             if(val+diff > 0){
                $(this).val(parseInt(val)+parseInt(diff))
                diff=0
             }else{
               $(this).val(0)
               diff=parseInt(val)+parseInt(diff)
             }
          }
       })
       
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="w1" class="warehouse" value="20">
<input type="number" id="w2" class="warehouse" value="0">
<input type="number" id="w3" class="warehouse" value="0">
```

Comment: thanks for solutions it works flawlessly, I just added a condition  `if ($(this).prop('max') >= (parseInt(val) + parseInt(diff)))` to obey max property. thanks again for your time and energy.